# Make - How to build dependencies, and how to define multiple targets?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, build-dependencies

i'm new to makefile and i would like to perform several operations.

my current makefile is as follows:

```
OBJECTS=radio_listener.o radio_app_comm_func.o
TARGET_EXECUTABLE=radio_listener

# Default target
all: ${TARGET_EXECUTABLE}

# Compile all required .o files this way
%.o: %.c
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    @gcc -c -g -m32 $< -o $@ 

# Compile target exe by combining all objects
${TARGET_EXECUTABLE}: ${OBJECTS}
    @echo "Linking $@"
    @gcc ${OBJECTS} -g -m32 -o $@

# Cleanup rule
clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up..."
    @rm -f *.o ${TARGET_EXECUTABLE}
    @echo "Done."

.PHONY: clean all
```

**1.** Say I execute 'make'. then change a MACRO define in **radio_app_comm_*types*.h**.

radio_app_comm_types.h is included in **radio_app_comm_func.h**.

after changing the MACRO, and executing 'make' again, i get *"Nothing to be done for 'all'*.

Obviously i somehow need to tell my Makefile, that radio_app_comm_func.h, is dependent on radio_app_comm_types.h.

How to do this?

**2.** The 2nd thing that interest me, is how to use the same Makefile, dor different executables.

Currently i have only **radio_listener** , but i plan on adding **radio_control**,**radio_server**, which their *h files* will also include **radio_app_comm_func.h**, and maybe some other h files (in order to use the relevant .c files of them.

How can i achieve this?
I'm looking to implement a flow as follows:

***a)*** Executing **make**, will compile all relevant files for each of the exe's, and in the end will create 3 different executables for me - **radio_listener, radio_control, radio_server**

***b)*** Executing **make server** (for example), will compile all relevant files that are needed **only** for **radio_server** (including looking for changes, say, in **radio_app_comm_types.h**) and finally will create only 1 executable - **radio_server** for me

***c)*** Executing **make controller** ...compile all needed for radio_control, etc (you get my meaning i guess)

I'm working on Ubuntu x64 system, if that's relevant.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that uses the advanced auto-dependency rules, and allows for multiple targets to be built.  Update the flags near the top and create new entries in `TARGETS` and make a new `xxx_SRC` variable to add new targets.

If you want the dependency files in the current directory you can change `DEPDIR` to be just `.` or else go through the makefile and delete references to it, either way.

```sh
TARGETS := exe1 exe2 exe3

DEPDIR = .d

exe1_SRC := foo.c bar.c
exe2_SRC := biz.c boz.c
exe3_SRC := bling.c blang.c

CC       := gcc

CFLAGS   := -g -O2
CPPFLAGS := -DXXX -I../include

LDFLAGS  :=  -L../lib
LDLIBS   :=  -lfoo -lbar

# ----- Nothing below here needs to be changed

.PHONY: all
all : $(TARGETS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
# For each target, depend on the .o files for its sources
$(TARGETS): $$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$$($$@_SRC))
        $(LINK.c) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

ALLSRC := $(foreach T,$(TARGETS),$($T_SRC))

.PHONY: clean
clean: 
        rm -f $(TARGETS) *.o $(DEPDIR)/*.d

# -----
# Advanced auto-dependency, from:
# http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

$(shell mkdir -p $(DEPDIR) >/dev/null)
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td

COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
POSTCOMPILE = mv -f $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td $(DEPDIR)/$*.d

%.o : %.c
%.o : %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d
        $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
        $(POSTCOMPILE)

$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: $(DEPDIR)/%.d

-include $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(ALLSRC)))
```

Comment: Why do you need a dependency on `$(DEPDIR)/%.d` at all?

Comment: It's explained in the blog post, but it's there so that if someone deletes the `.d` files then the object file is considered out of date and rebuilt.  Otherwise you may not recompile things when you should if someone goes in and deletes the `.d` files by hand.

Comment: this line: `CC       := gcc` only works if the gcc utility directory is in the PATH environment variable.   Much better to use: `CC := /usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: regarding this line: ` rm -f $(TARGETS) *.o $(DEPDIR)/*.d` if DEPDIR is set to nothing or the `DEPDIR` string eliminated, then this line will try to remove *.d files from the root directory.  suggest modifying the macro DEPDIR to include the `/` and remove that `/` from this line.     Other than that detail, a very nice makefile

Comment: I used the posted makefile under linux (with target/source list changes as needed)  It works.   Thanks for posting this.  Does it also work under windows?

Comment: Personally I don't prefer using `/usr/bin/gcc`.  First, if GCC is really in `/usr/bin` then it will be found anyway: no one runs a shell without `/usr/bin` in their `PATH`.  Second, some people prefer to use alternate versions of the compiler than the one installed by default.  In general it's my preference to allow the user to choose their `PATH`.  Alternatively it might be best to set `PATH` in the makefile rather than using hardcoded paths for each tool.  For `DEPDIR`; that's why I recommended setting it to `.` if you wanted to use the current directory.  But your solution works too.

Comment: It will work on Windows provided you have sufficient tooling: GCC and `mv`.  Else you need to rework it to use Windows commands like `rename` and find a way to convince your Windows compiler to generate dependency files.  There are some hints on how to do it in my blog post if your compiler doesn't provide this functionality out of the box.

Comment: @MadScientist, thanks for the comment.
i've just tried to use your explained implementation and have a few questions:

1. I've tried only for ONE executable at the moment, and getting:
`gcc: warning: radio_listener.o: linker input file unused because linking not done`
`gcc: warning: radio_app_comm_func.o: linker input file unused because linking not done`
The edits i've done can be found here:
[link](http://pastebin.com/gpWGhZdr)

2. The dep auto-generate means i don't have to explicitly indicate the includes chain - the `make` will do so, and if an h is changed will, will re-compile?

Thanks!

Comment: (1) You should never add `-c` to your CFLAGS variable.  That's your problem.  Take it out.  First it's already part of the default variable I used, and second it means you can't use CFLAGS with your linker (because `-c` tells the compiler to generate an object file, not an executable) but you almost always DO want your CFLAGS to be used on the link line. (2) yes that's correct.  You don't need to specify header file dependecies by hand.

Comment: @MadScientist, thanks - i've removed the `-c` from CFLAGS.
Now i'm getting :
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lradio_listener
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lradio_app_comm_func`
which i'm guessing realted to my LDLIBS part, but as i understood from your example, should have `-lfoo -lbar` (for example)..
although i didn't understood why it contains only file names only related to `exe1_SRC` and not the others

Comment: `-lfoo` tells the linker to link a library `libfoo.so` or `libfoo.a`, but you need to tell the linker _where_ to find your libraries (what directories to look in).  This is done with the `-L` flag in `LDFLAGS` variable.  I'm not sure what to say about your last sentence.  The above makefile assumes that all the executables need to link the same libraries.  If you want to link different libraries per executable then more needs to be done.

Comment: @MadScientist, i'm sorry, this all kind of new to me.
when you say **you need to tell the linker where to find your libraries**, i'm not sure what libraries you're refering to.. **what directories to look in** - look for what? 
Sorry for maybe asking some dumb questions, makefile is hard for me

Comment: This has nothing to do with makefiles: you need to understand how to invoke your compiler, what a library is, etc.  A makefile is just a way to run commands, which can do anything.  It's up to you to make sure the commands you tell `make` to run do what you want.  The problems you're having are related to not knowing the compiler's options, not makefiles.  If you entered those same commands at your shell prompt, without make, you'd get the same errors.  The documentation for your compiler will say what these options mean and how to use them.  Or, ask a separate question.

Comment: But, from your questions, I don't know why you're using `-lradio_app_comm_func` at all.  It seems like you don't have a library by that name, so if you don't have a library you shouldn't use the `-l` flag.  If you don't have any libraries that you need, then just leave the `LDLIBS` variable empty.  `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` are mostly only needed if you need to link in other libraries of code.  You don't use them to link in the object files created by the compiler for your source files.

Answer (score 0):

here is a makefile that incorporates generation of dependencies.

```
    SHELL = /bin/sh

    target1 := <first executable name>
    target2 := <second executable name>
    target3 := <third executable name>

    #
    # details for target1
    #
    SRC1 := <list of files for target1
    OBJ1 := $(SRC1:.c=.o) 

    #
    # details for target2
    #
    SRC2 := <list of files for target2
    OBJ2 := $(SRC2:.c=.o) 

    #
    # details for target3
    #
    SRC3 := <list of files for target3
    OBJ3 := $(SRC3:.c=.o)

    MAKE    :=  /usr/bin/make

    CC      :=  /usr/bin/gcc

    CP      :=  cp

    MV      := mv

    LDFLAGS :=  

    DEBUG   :=  -ggdb3

    CCFLAGS :=  $(DEBUG) -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -Wconversion

    #CPPFLAGS += =MD

    LIBDIRS :=  -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib
    LIBS    :=  -l<library short name> ...


    .PHONY: all
    all : $(target1)  $(target2) $(target3)


    #
    # link the .o files into the executable 
    # using the linker flags
    # -- explicit rule
    #
    $(target1): $(OBJ1)
        #
        # ======= $@ Link Start =========
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ1) $(LIBDIRS) $(LIBS)
        # ======= $@ Link Done ==========
        #

    $(target2): $(OBJ2)
        #
        # ======= $@ Link Start =========
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ2) $(LIBDIRS) $(LIBS)
        # ======= $@ Link Done ==========
        #

    $(target3): $(OBJ3)
        #
        # ======= $@ Link Start =========
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ3) $(LIBDIRS) $(LIBS)
        # ======= $@ Link Done ==========
        #

    #
    #create dependancy files -- inference rule
    #
    %.d: %.c 
        # 
        # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
        $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
        sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
        rm -f $@.$$$$
        # ========= END $< TO $@ =========

    # 
    # compile the .c files into .o files using the compiler flags
    # -- inference rule
    #
    %.o: %.c %.d 
        # 
        # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I. 
        # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
        # 



    .PHONY: clean
    clean: 
        # ========== CLEANING UP ==========
        rm -f *.o
        rm -f $(target1) $(target2) $(target3)
        rm -f *.d
        # ========== DONE ==========

    # include the contents of all the .d files
    # note: the .d files contain:
    # <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependencies for that .c file 
    # I.E. the #include'd header files
    # wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
    #
    ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
    -include $(DEP)
    endif
```

Comment: This is using an outdated method of dependency tracking.  If you're going to provide full solutions like this, which are helpful, I recommend reading http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ and updating your solution accordingly.  Also, please use the standard `CFLAGS` variable not `CCFLAGS`.  And you forgot to include `CPPFLAGS` in your compile line.  And you wrote `LIBDIRs` where you meant `LIBDIRS` (make is case-sensitive).  Better to just use the default make variables for all these rules.  Cheers!

Comment: Actually, using any kind of `make depend` during the compile step/rule is not a good idea as it will always be executed (thereby causing the re-execution of `make`)   In other words, the suggested link is presenting a poor practice.   By keeping the creation of dependencies as a separate rule so it only gets executed when necessary, does not cause a re-execution of `make`.  Of note is that CPPFLAGS is only of interest if something 'special' is to be preformed at preprocess time.  Since nothing 'special' is being preformed, there is no need for the CPPFLAGS.

Comment: Your correct that I mis-typed the name LIBDIRS at some point in the file..  I'll fix that

Comment: Placing the *.d files in a separate directory just clutters the directory structure, complicates the project layout, and is totally unneeded.  Also, when invoking the `clean` target, if using the 'bare' include statement, then `make` will recreate all the *.d files  during the `clean` operation.   That is why the `ifneq` around the `include ` statement, so that statement is ignored when the target is `clean`.  The presented link fails to properly  handle that case.

Comment: The exact spelling of the macro names is only of importance if the 'pre-defined'  names are being used within the makefile, without using any override.   such as having no explicit compile step  etc.  That is not the case with the posted answer.

Comment: @MadScientist,  Feel free to post your own answer, presenting how you think the makefile should be written.  Then we can all learn of this 'new' method of producing dependency files

Comment: (1) Please read the post carefully.  It starts with poor (but common) practices and proceeds to best practices.  Or just skip down to http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#combine if you prefer to ignore all the "how we get there" stuff and just see the results.  That entire post is about _automatic_ dependency generation and doesn't relay on `make depend`.  (2) `CPPFLAGS` absolutely must be specified during compilation (the `%.o : %.c` rule).

Comment: (3) In the advanced model there's no need to handle `clean` specially because we don't automatically create any `.d` files via `include`, so we don't have to avoid it during `clean`.  (4) Whether it's more cluttered to leave the `.d` files in the same directory as sources or put them all in a subdirectory is a personal choice: the advanced method works either way. (4) It's important to use macro names everyone is familiar with, so people using your makefiles can work with them more easily without having to learn special customizations.

Comment: Also you should never set the `MAKE` variable in a makefile.  `make` will set this value properly for you and resetting it will break things.

Comment: I suggest never building into the source directory because this leads to inconsistent builds when the compilation mode/flags change. Build into a separate build directory for each compilation mode.

Comment: In my own projects, for the make file, I always include the makefile as a dependency.  Then when the make file changes, everything gets rebuilt.  That way, never a problem

Comment: @MadScientist,  As a suggested before, just post a makefile for this specific question from the OP, that fully incorporates this 'new' method AND which, with no changes other than the link statements, can be immediately used in a different project.  We would all appreciate such an example.  Note: my posted answer is a trimmed down version of what I have used in many projects, that contain 100s to 1000s of files, with no changes.  Does it matter if the `make` is done before I can get my finger off the 'enter' key or not until I'm looking up to see if there are any errors displayed?

Comment: I did post one, see above.

Comment: I'm wondering about the downvote.  As the posted answer works for the question the OP posted   So even if it is not the MOST EFFICIENT / MOST MODERN method (which it never claimed to be) it is a correct answer